# Can I use the static keyword for classes and structs in C++?

Tags: c++

I understand that you can use the `static` keyword for functions and variables to prevent them from being visible from other files. Can I use it for classes/structs? For example, inside a function, I use a struct that only that function uses, but I don't want to be able to use it from outside that file and I don't return that struct.

Comment: You don't need to? Unless you are talking about having a variable of class type at file scope?

Comment: @UnholySheep C++ has ODR

Comment: `static` is not a visibility modifier.  It controls *storage duration* and/or *linkage* (depending on context).

Comment: @user253751 it does.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use the static keyword for classes and structs in C++?

No. However, you can define classes in an anonymous namespace which will prevent it from being named in other translation units.